# The number of ways to choose 7 distinct natural...

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> The number of ways to choose 7 distinct natural numbers from the set of first 100 natural numbers such that any two chosen numbers differ at least by 7 can be expressed as ${n \choose 7}$. Find the value of $n.$

**My attempt**: According to me we have to select any of the $7$ numbers of our choice, so $n = 100$.

Comment: But that would allow selections like $1,4,10,36,42,67,71$ where some terms differ by $<7$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $n$ were to be $100$, one would be able to pick $1$ and $2$, which do not match the condition that the numbers must differ at least by $7$. In fact, this problem comes down to a [stars-and-bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), where the bars are the indices of the numbers chosen, and at least $6$ numbers must be in between each bar. If we select $7$ numbers, $7$ places must be reserved for the bars and an additional $(7-1) (7-1) = 36$ places must be reserved for the intermediate numbers. This leaves $100 - 43 = 57$ free places which need to be distributed among the $8$ slots, and the total number of valid combinations thus equals:

$${57 + 8 - 1 \choose 8 - 1} = {64 \choose 7}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\underline{A\; solution\; w/o\; using\; stars\; and\; bars}$

- Take $100$ white balls and remove $6\times6 = 36$, so $64$ remain. Put them in a row.
- Color any $7$ of the row of balls red, **thus** $\binom{64}7$ **possibilities.**
- Insert $6$ each of the removed balls immediately to the right of the first six red balls.
- The positions of the red balls in each such sequence satisfies the criteria

Comment: Really is it different?

Comment: @jiten: Of course *essentially* the same, just more intuitive for a problem perhaps not immediately perceivable as a stars and bars type.

Comment: Although, not clear but hope the generalized version should be: # ways to choose $m$ distinct naturals from set of first $l$ naturals s.t. any two chosen numbers differ at least by $k$ can be expressed as $\binom{l-(m-1)(k-1)}{m}$. Sorry, am still confused why distance between numbers is at least $k(=7)$. Might be not clear with the question. Request a practical (enumerable by hand) example with say,  need to pick $m=3$ numbers with a least distance of $k=3$ from a small value (of size of set) of first few naturals, i.e. $l$.

Comment: Kindly see my post at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3941577/424260

Comment: @jiten: Seen, thanks. The formula you have given in the previous comment is correct. Coloring balls etc is for a more intuitive approach. The crux is that **(a)** even if we first chose two **adjacent** "objects", by inserting $6$ "objects" in between, we create a **minimum** gap of $7$ between them. **(b)** we need only six such "spacers" because the last chosen "object" doesn't need a "spacer" after it **(c)** the "objects" are numbered from $1-100$ **after** the "spacers" have been inserted.